# I am unable to understand why this suggest edit was rejected

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12975465). I am not able to understand why my suggested edit was rejected and the person rejecting it made almost the same changes. As far as I know it should be "approved and edited" and not "rejected and edited".

Comment: Why are you editing off-topic questions?  You should be downvoting them and (when able at 3k) vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) the person who edited the post and ask. To be fair, removing a couple of question marks and capitalizing PC is just a minor improvement on your edit, so <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> would be more logical.

That said, neither your edit nor the current one do anything about the clunky grammar of the post. Nor *can* they do anything about the fact that this question is better posted (and maybe already asked before) on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Seems appropriate. Yes that should have been posted in server fault.